# RecursionError in views.py django

Tags: python, django

This is throwing me a recursion error.

It first suggested that I put in the argument 'request' in the signup() but then I received a new error.

Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import signup
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import signup

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = signup(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            post = register_form.save()
            message = format_html("Hi {0}, Thank you for signing up with us! See your profile <a href=''>{1}</a>".format(register_form.cleaned_data['name'], "here"))
            return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':register_form, 'message': message})
        else:
            message = register_form.errors
            form = signup(request)
            return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':form, 'message': message})

    else:
        form = signup(request)

    return render(request, 'myapp/register.html', {'signup':form})
```

throws:

> if request.method == 'POST': RecursionError: maximum recursion depth
>   exceeded in comparison

Comment: you're calling `signup` from within itself. That's what the problem is. Looks like it's supposed to be a form object, in which case import it (under a different name if it's called `signup` - but it's more idiomatic to call it something like `SignupForm`, and with an uppercase first letter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem are these lines

```
...
from .models import signup
...
def signup(request):
...
 if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = signup(request.POST)
...
```

You're redefining signup() causing it to call itself indefinitely. You'll need to rename one of these methods.